# How to copy file to folder if I know incomplete name of that folder using ANT

Tags: tomcat, build, ant, terminal

Below id the code snippet

```
<property name="apache.dst.dir" value="../../apache-tomcat-7.0.79/webapps" />

<copy todir="${apache.dst.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${dstdir}">
        <include name="api.war" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

I am trying to copy the war file to webapps directory under apache-tomcat. However different users might have a different version of tomcat and hence the folder name might vary.It will be apache-tomcat-something. How do I specify that ? I want my ant file to look for a folder that starts with apache-tomcat-*/webapps and copy the file in webapps under that folder.

I added * however it creates a new folder rather than finding the folder with similar name.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant's `property` task doesn't work with wildcards, so you'll have to use a resource collection to find the desired directory. Here's how I would recommend doing it:

```
<dirset id="tomcat.dir" dir="../.." includes="apache-tomcat-*" />

<fail message="Multiple Tomcat directories found in ${tomcat.parent.dir}.${line.separator}${toString:tomcat.dir}">
    <condition>
        <resourcecount refid="tomcat.dir" when="greater" count="1" />
    </condition>
</fail>

<fail message="No Tomcat directory found in ${tomcat.parent.dir}.">
    <condition>
        <resourcecount refid="tomcat.dir" when="less" count="1" />
    </condition>
</fail>

<pathconvert refid="tomcat.dir" property="tomcat.dir" />

<property name="tomcat.webapps.dir" location="${tomcat.dir}/webapps" />

<copy todir="${tomcat.webapps.dir}" file="${dstdir}/api.war" flatten="true" />
```

Explanation:

1. Use the `dirset` type to collect directories located in `../..` that follow the pattern "apache-tomcat-*". This will be stored as an Ant `path` with ID "tomcat.dir". (Feel free to rename these values to "apache" or whatever; this is just my preference because Apache makes many different products.)
2. Since the `dirset` might collect multiple directories, you'll probably want to fail the build if this happens. Otherwise you'll end up with a confusing error later in the script.
3. Similarly, you'll probably want to fail the build if no directories are found. The `dirset` type will not fail the build on its own if it finds nothing.
4. Use the `pathconvert` task to create a property from the `tomcat.dir` path. I gave them the same name, but this doesn't need to be the case.
5. Use the `property` task to create a property specifically for your destination directory. Note the use of the `location` attribute in place of the `value` attribute. This will cause the property value to be resolved into a canonical path with file separators that are appropriate for the user's OS (i.e. if the user is on Windows, forward slashes will be converted to back slashes).
6. Copy to the directory defined above. I assume you want to remove any parent directories from your war file, so I included the `flatten="true"` attribute, but if this isn't the case, just go ahead and remove that part.